# Login on Facebook - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, facebook

I would like to connection to Facebook account. So i created a simple method to login on facebook.
Code looks like that:

```
  startFacebook() {
    window['fbAsyncInit'] = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: environment.facebookAppId,
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v10.0',
      });

      FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
      let js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {
        return;
      }
      js = d.createElement(s);
      js.id = id;
      js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js';
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    })(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk');
  }

  loginFacebook(userService: UserService) {
    FB.getLoginStatus((response) => {
      if (response.status === 'connected') {
        userService.loginFacebookUser(response);
      } else {
        FB.login((responseLogin) => {
          console.log(responseLogin);
          if (responseLogin.authResponse) {
            userService.loginFacebookUser(responseLogin);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Everything was working fine to about Monday.
Now when I call "loginFacebook" I can see a dialog window by Facebook but immediately I got a message from Facebook. I mean call "FB.login((responseLogin) => {" not waiting for login user but immediately send status "unknown" to me.
When the user is logged before - call "loginFacebook" is working fine.

Facebook changed something or am I doing something wrong?

edit: I discovered that a problem exists only on Google Chrome but on a few computers.

Best Regards,
Kris.

Comment: There are several other reports with the same issue, I guess Facebook SDK changed something. I have the same problem and still looking for solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I know that I'm not alone with this :)

Comment: Today everything is ok, so they fixed a problem.